Why does the query using SYSDATE to fetch the most recent date from the commandes table return no results?
SELECT *
FROM commandes
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datecommande) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE)
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datecommande) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE); 

I need to return data from 2020, but the query using SYSDATE returns no results, as SYSDATE is showing 2024. Why is this happening?

Um...the current year is 2024 right?

in datecommend current year 2020

Do you want all records from the latest year in the table?

Please provide sample input data and the expected result.

You tagged your request with two different tools SQL Developer and PL/SQL Developer. You won't be using both, I guess. And as this is a simple SQL question, it doesn't matter which tool you are using, anyway. You also tagged your request with database, but your question is not about designing a database. I've removed all these tags. I've also replaced the oracle tag. We use oracle-database instead. Please read the tag descriptions when adding tags to your requests.

If you want the data from the most-recent year in the table then, from Oracle 12, you can use:
SELECT *
FROM   commandes
ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datecommande) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;

If you want the most-recent month's data then:
SELECT *
FROM   commandes
ORDER BY TRUNC(datecommande, 'MM') DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;


If you want data from the current year then:
SELECT *
FROM   commandes
WHERE  datecommande >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY')
AND    datecommande <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY'), 12);


If you want data from 2020 then use:
SELECT *
FROM   commandes
WHERE  datecommande >= DATE '2020-01-01'
AND    datecommande <  DATE '2021-01-01';


In your query you have not mentioned that you want to filter data from 2020 , since you are using sysdate it will give current date and time thats why your query is not working, based on current year it is checking 2024 . try something like this to  get all records from 2020:
SELECT * FROM commandes WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datecommande) = 2020;

Edit : If you dont want to hard code 2020 to filter it and get the most recent year from table itself , you can try something like this , by providing sub query to get most recent year from table and then having filter in where clause :
SELECT *
FROM commandes 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datecommande) = 
  (SELECT MAX(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datecommande)) FROM commandes);


I don't know the most recent year in the table and I want to find it with sysdate

you need to use sub query in your where clause something like below , this will filter based on most recent year in table : SELECT * FROM commandes WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datecommande) = ( SELECT MAX(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datecommande)) FROM commandes );   let me know if it works for what you are trying to achieve

@PRAIIIZ Fou: SYSDATE is a function that returns the current date and time. It doesn't have anything to do with your data. It tells you the same thing as a simple watch on your wrist. Would you look at your watch in order to learn what the most recent year in some table in some database is? Probably not.
